# Ajax Control Toolkit Html Editor doesn't save content from DesignerMode

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I upgraded AjaxControlToolkit (ACT) version from 7.x.x to 16.1.0.0 (latest stable version). I have been using ACT Html Editor on aspx page and working fine but after upgrading to latest version, I see that the content doesn't get saved to database. The content value doesn't get updated on save button click. Recently I found something weird that if I click on HtmlMode or PreviewMode at least once from DesignerMode of HtmlEditor, the content gets saved and works fine. 
Here is what I followed to upgrade: [AjaxControlToolkit Upgrade](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Upgrade%20your%20project%20to%20AjaxControlToolkit%20v15.1&referringTitle=Documentation)

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by doing some research. I contacted author of AjaxControlToolkit and he recommended to move to [HtmlEditorExtender](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/HtmlEditorExtender/HtmlEditorExtender.aspx) as HtmlEditor is going to be deprecated from next version. So I moved to HtmlEditorExtender and it solved my problem.

Hopefully it will be helpful to someone.
Thanks.